# How Google Drive Chrome App has access to copy paste clipboard?

Tags: google-chrome, clipboard, google-drive-api

Recently, Drive documents have acquired the ability to do copy paste, directly from the app instead of relying on copy paste keyboard shortcuts. This is only possible when you are using Chrome and have the Google Drive app installed.

When I look at the Chrome app documentation, there is no mention of a clipboard API. Am I missing something? Or is this simply a secret API that Google does not want to release for general use?